# How to override method and call base in stub with Microsoft Fakes

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

I'd like to do an override with MS Fakes that would call the base code and I can't find how to do it. Here's an example

Given

```
public class Potato
{
   public virtual string Peel(PeelingMethod peelingMethod)
   {
      return "potato peeled";
   }
}
```

When I create my Stub

```
new StubPotato()
{
    PeelPeelingMethod = (p) =>
    {
       //Doesn't compile!
       base.Peel(p);
       Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this, I am pretty new to the MS Fakes framework so maybee there is something i don't know about it.

Comment: I believe there's a `CallsBase` property on stubs that does this.

Comment: I thought it was made to call base method if no override were found. I will check that out and come back about it

Comment: From MSDN : "If you do not provide a delegate for a virtual method, Fakes can either provide the default behavior, or it can call the method in the base class. To have the base method called, set the CallBase property"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549174.aspx

Comment: Well, you may be out of luck. The `base` pointer doesn't exist inside the delegate, because the delegate is a separate class. This isn't too strange though, considering the point of Fakes is to **not** use the base class.

Comment: Yeah I guess. I found a terrible workaround, I'll post it here if someone happens to need it

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, you should post it and accept it. Someone might even improve it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it is pretty disgusting but it works. I'll put it here if someone needs. I'll reuse my example (that I edited because I didn't test this answer with a method that returns void)

```
var stubPotato = new StubPotato()
{
    PeelPeelingMethod = (p) =>
    {
        //Base method call
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Potato).GetMethod("Peel", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var methodPtr = methodInfo.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
        var baseMethod = (Func<PeelingMethod,string>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Func<PeelingMethod,string>), stubPotato , methodPtr);
        string baseResult = baseMethod(p);

        //Code for the "override"
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }
}
```